# MySQL: character set utf8 giving error with datetime

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and wants to create this table after reading tutorial I wrote this command but on MySQL Workbench it shows error for 4 line created_at attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE tweetMelbourne (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `geo_type` VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `created_at` DATETIME CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
    `geo_coordinates_latitude` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `geo_coordinates_longitude` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `place_full_name` VARCHAR(35) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `place_country` VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `place_type` VARCHAR(18) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `place_bounding_box_type` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `place_bounding_box_coordinates_NE_lat` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `place_bounding_box_coordinates_NE_long` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `place_bounding_box_coordinates_SW_lat` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `place_bounding_box_coordinates_SW_long` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `place_country_code` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `place_name` VARCHAR(17) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `text` VARCHAR(140) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `user_id` INT,
    `user_verified` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `user_followers_count` INT,
    `user_listed_count` INT,
    `user_friends_count` INT,
    `user_location` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `user_following` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `user_geo_enabled` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `user_lang` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

> Error is :

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

have your tried with removing 'CHARACTER SET utf8'

Comment: yup it removes the error but my question why we are not providing character set utf8 for datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys it worked. I used `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` at the end. So, I think no need to define character set for datetime because its made up of numbers and doesn't include character.